# Routing decide controller by host

Tags: symfony, controller, routes, host

I tried to select a controller by host. 
This is what I did in my `routing.yml`:

```
rout_default:
    resource: "@DefaultBundle/Controller/"
    type:     annotation
    prefix:   /

rout1:
    resource: "@DefaultBundle/Controller/Controller1Controller.php"
    type:     annotation
    prefix:   /
    host: example.com

rout2:
    resource: "@DefaultBundle/Controller/Controller2Controller.php"
    type:     annotation
    prefix:   /
    host: example2.com
```

In the contollers I have following Actions:

```
/**
 * @Route("/data", name="data")
 */
public function dataAction()
{
    //...
}
```

I have these functions in both controllers. I know that the action and the name is the same, but I hoped, that the system will notice the difference by the host.

If I type `debug:router` in the console, there is only the route of `rout2`. The other one is not visible.

Thank you for your help.

Comment: try debugging with the command `router:match` as example lauching `php app/console router:match /data --host example.com` and see if match

Comment: example2.com matches, but not the other one. Route "de__RG__data" almost matches but host "example.com" does not match the requirement ("example2.com")

Comment: very strange.. try removing the `name` attribute from the `@Route` annotation

Comment: Then it workes. But now i can't open it in twig wit path()

Comment: of course, you can use the name assigned by default (as described [here](https://symfony.com/doc/current/bundles/SensioFrameworkExtraBundle/annotations/routing.html#route-name)) or see the route name that should be displayed from the debug command (or `route:match`)

Comment: let me know if it works for you :)

Comment: Than you 4 your help i think i can manage this now

Comment: You can post your solution as an answer so the user can find a solution for the same problem or if my solution fit your needed I can post my comments as an answer so you can close your question

Comment: I tried to remove all names from my routs, but i used them a lot of times. In menu builder and so on. Do you know any solution that i can use the names? My idea is that i ask about the host in the aktion.